# SQLITE3 query to return posts that do not have specific tags

Tags: sqlite

Consider the typical scenario of a blog that has POSTS and TAGS.

I need to locate all POSTS that do not have TAGS that are in a given list of TAGS.

What this means is that posts that do not have any of the listed tags are selected. Or, to put it conversely, posts that have any tags from the list are not selected.

**How would I construct a suitable query to do this?**

For the purpose of this example, the query should work with a SQLITE3 database that has a POSTS table, a TAGS table and a POSTS_TAGS table such that the query

```
select p.title, t.name from posts p 
 inner join posts_tags pt on pt.post_id = p.id
 inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tag_id
```

returns all posts joined to their tags (posts with multiple tags are listed multiple times).

I think the answer lies around getting all tags for a post so I tried using `group_concat` to reduce this to one row per post with all tags but could not make it work. Here is what I tried:

```
select p.title, t.name, group_concat(t.name) from posts p
 inner join posts_tags pt on pt.post_id = p.id 
 inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tag_id;
```

but this returns one row being the last post with all tags of all posts. The next step would be to exclude rows where the tags contain any of the excluded ones.

I'll keep trying to solve this but if anyone can come up with a query to return all POSTS that do not have any of the speified TAGS then that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) to find all the tags for a post, and then just use NOT EXISTS to check if no tags were found:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM posts_tags
                  WHERE posts_tags.post_id = posts.id
                    AND posts_tags.tag_id IN (1, 22, 333, ...))
```

---

It would also be possible to use an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) and check where the join did not match any tag record:

```sql
SELECT posts.*
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN posts_tags ON  posts.id = posts_tags.post_id
                     AND posts_tags.tag_id IN (1, 22, 333, ...)
WHERE posts_tags.tag_id IS NULL
```

... but this is not quite as efficient because it would require the database to construct all the joined records before they are filtered out.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. I had tried a subquery before posting here but it was late and I didn't do it quite right. With the guidance from this answer, I was able to revisit what I had done and it now does what I need - so that you CL.